# MySQL SELECT: Returning multiple columns based on a column value in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm reading in rows from a single table containing file meta information. One of the columns, acl,  contains a flag (0,1 or 2) mapping to (unrestricted, restricted or privaleged). I'd like to create a SELECT query that will return file data based on two PHP variables, $userId and $isAdmin. The logic is as follows:

- Return the file info row if acl = 0 irrespective of $userId or $isAdmin values
- Return the file info row if acl = 1 AND $isAdmin is TRUE
- Return the file info row if acl = 2 IF $userId = fileownerid (where fileownerid is a column in the table storing the ID of the owner who uploaded the file)

So basically I'm doing a query on the table and only returning the rows that the user is allowed to see

I've tried using all sorts of CASE and IF statements in a subquery but can't solve it. Starting to thing it's not possible to do without processing the SQL result in PHP.

Any gurus see a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select * from file where (acl = 0) or (acl = 1 and ? = 'TRUE') or (acl = 2 and ? = fileownerid)`
then bind isAdmin and userid to variables 1 and 2.

Comment: Cheers Paul...so much simpler then I thought; Sometimes you can't see the woods for the trees!

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should do the job:

```
$qry = 'SELECT * FROM yourtable 
WHERE (acl = 0)
OR (acl = 1 AND '.$isAdmin.')
OR (acl = 2 AND '.$userId.' = fileownerid)';
```